# How to combine multiple Excel dynamic arrays in the form of a database full outer join

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, dynamic

I want to join two dynamic arrays into a single array with all elements from both, like an SQL Full Join.

Dynamic Array 1 (Staff):

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| StaffID1 | StaffName1 |
| StaffID2 | StaffName2 |
| StaffID3 | StaffName3 |

Dynamic Array 2 (Subjects):

| Column C |
| --- |
| Subject1 |
| Subject2 |
| Subject3 |
| Subject4 |

Desired Output Array (Staff x Subjects):

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| StaffID1 | StaffName1 | Subject1 |
| StaffID1 | StaffName1 | Subject2 |
| StaffID1 | StaffName1 | Subject3 |
| StaffID1 | StaffName1 | Subject4 |
| StaffID2 | StaffName2 | Subject1 |
| StaffID2 | StaffName2 | Subject2 |
| StaffID2 | StaffName2 | Subject3 |
| StaffID2 | StaffName2 | Subject4 |
| StaffID3 | StaffName3 | Subject1 |
| StaffID3 | StaffName3 | Subject2 |
| StaffID3 | StaffName3 | Subject3 |
| StaffID3 | StaffName3 | Subject4 |

I've had varying success generating the output array. I understand I need to repeat Dynamic Array 1 for the size of Dynamic Array 2 using SEQUENCE, but I am struggling to create the Subjects column of the Output Array. Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: How is this a join when there is no ID in the second table and no foreign key in the first? Don't you need those for a join? I only did SQL very briefly so pardon my ignorance. Either way I don't see what rules you are using for generating the third table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir has given a better solution to the query, however one can try this way as well. It essentially repeats the no of rows based on the no of rows both the array has.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `J3`

```
=LET(r,ROWS(A3#),
rr,ROWS(D3#),
c,COLUMNS(A3#),
x,INDEX(A3#,SEQUENCE(r*rr,,1,1/rr),SEQUENCE(,c)),
y,INDEX(D3#,MOD((SEQUENCE(r*rr)-1),rr)+1),
HSTACK(x,y))
```

---

Answer (score 4):

If input are two dynamic arrays, and you want to combine these, here is one option:

[image]

Formula in `F1`:

```
=SORT(DROP(REDUCE(0,D1#,LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,IFERROR(HSTACK(A1#,b),b)))),1))
```